# Filter data based on multiple parameters in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects in the form, which can have more than 2 objects. 
This is the data I get from the server.

```
[
        {processId : 1, processName : "process1", country : "germany", companyCode:"IB" , companyHiringType:"FRE", masterClauses:[
      {clauseName : "tst dummy", description : "dummy desc",  clauseId : 1, parentClause : null, titleDisplayFlag :false, textFlag: false, clauseType:"" , processid: 1, subClauseId:null, subClauseSequence:null ,texts :[
        {text : "dummy",textId : 1, sequenceNo :1}
      ]}
    ]},

        {processId : 2, processName : "process2", country : "Finland", companyCode:"IL" , companyHiringType:"Lat", masterClauses:[
      {clauseName : "test1", description : "test1Demo",  clauseId : 1, parentClause : null, titleDisplayFlag :false, textFlag: false, clauseType:"" , processid: 2, subClauseId:null, subClauseSequence:null ,texts :[
        {text : "dummy text",textId : 1, sequenceNo: 1}
      ]}
    ]}
  ]
  ]
```

I have a form in my **html**

```
<form #filterForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addFilter(filterForm)" autocomplete="off">
      <h4 class="h4Header">Filter by
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"  (click)=closeRightMenu($event) class="filterClose icon x-24 close-icon float-right"></a>
      </h4>
      <!-- -->
      <mat-accordion class="cus-accordion">


        <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>Company</mat-panel-title>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-radio-group required [ngModel]="selected" class="custom-radio block-radio-group"  aria-label="Select an option"  name="companyCode">
            <mat-radio-button class="block-radio-button"  *ngFor="let com of companyA;index as i"  [value]="com"  disableRipple="true">{{com}}</mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>
        </mat-expansion-panel>

        <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>Country</mat-panel-title>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-radio-group required [ngModel]="selected" class="custom-radio block-radio-group"  aria-label="Select an option"  name="country">
            <mat-radio-button class="block-radio-button"  *ngFor="let com of country;index as i"  [value]="com.countryName"  disableRipple="true">{{com.countryName}}</mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>
        </mat-expansion-panel>

        <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>Process</mat-panel-title>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-radio-group required [ngModel]="selected" class="custom-radio block-radio-group"  aria-label="Select an option"  name="companyHiringType">
            <mat-radio-button class="block-radio-button"  *ngFor="let com of hiring;index as i"  [value]="com"  disableRipple="true">{{com}}</mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>
        </mat-expansion-panel>

        <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>Module</mat-panel-title>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-radio-group required [ngModel]="selected" class="custom-radio block-radio-group"  aria-label="Select an option"  name="processName">
            <mat-radio-button class="block-radio-button"  *ngFor="let com of moduleA;index as i"  [value]="com.processName"  disableRipple="true">{{com.processName}}</mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
    <div class="bottomUtil">
      <div class="row nomarLR padTB16">
        <div class="col-6 padR8">
          <button mat-flat-button class="primary-btn btnfullWdth" type="submit">Apply</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 padL8">
          <button mat-flat-button class="secondary-btn btnfullWdth" (click)="testingButton()">Reset</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

The user selects the value from the radio buttons and the data displayed after it should be based on the radio buttons selected. 
For example, if the user selects

```
processName : "process1", country : "germany", companyCode:"IB" and companyHiringType:"FRE"
```

The data I want to be displayed is

```
clauseName : "tst dummy", description : "dummy desc" and from the nested array I should get text : "dummy"
```

Is there a way we can filter the data based on 4 parameters?

Comment: Hi, it would be quite helpful if you prepared a stackblitz with your code.

Comment: (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tt9oxu) This is something I was working on, when you save after selecting the radio buttons, console has an object which i want to use to filter my result. Please let me know If you want me to update the Code. I am using the radio buttons as form to push the data in finalArray in ser.services.ts and I want to use the object in console to filter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to filter. For example, in your array of object you only want to show the ones where `country` is `germany` if that radio is selected? Also, how does that array of object relate to your form, sorry I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: i want to show data where, for example, country is germany, process name is process1, companyCode is IB and companyHiringType is FRE, all together. Like one of them online shopping sites where you can select multiple filters and product is displayed accordingly

Comment: Hi again! In your stackblitz, where is the data you get from the server? (where are you storing it?)

Comment: I have hardcoded the data for now in the service file. Its the same format as that of what I get from the server. I call them in my component class and then work on them

Comment: Sorry it still is very unclear and your stackblitz contains too much code. Can you edit it you include just the relevant code? Also, can you please update the question with the input and desired output.

Comment: I understand, the code on my local machine is way too messed up. I cant make sense of it. I''ll update you with the new code. Thank You

Comment: @NicholasK hi, please do check (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379976/angular-show-data-on-the-user-screen-based-on-the-values-from-the-form) I have tried to simplify the code and defined the data in a better way. Cheers. Let me know if you need some more explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per understanding your code/problem

Here is the data which will came from server

```
var data = [
  {
    processId: 1,
    processName: "process1",
    country: "germany",
    companyCode: "IB",
    companyHiringType: "FRE",
    masterClauses: [
      {
        clauseName: "tst dummy",
        description: "dummy desc",
        clauseId: 1,
        parentClause: null,
        titleDisplayFlag: false,
        textFlag: false,
        clauseType: "",
        processid: 1,
        subClauseId: null,
        subClauseSequence: null,
        texts: [
          {
            text: "dummy",
            textId: 1,
            sequenceNo: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    processId: 2,
    processName: "process2",
    country: "Finland",
    companyCode: "IL",
    companyHiringType: "Lat",
    masterClauses: [
      {
        clauseName: "test1",
        description: "test1Demo",
        clauseId: 1,
        parentClause: null,
        titleDisplayFlag: false,
        textFlag: false,
        clauseType: "",
        processid: 2,
        subClauseId: null,
        subClauseSequence: null,
        texts: [
          {
            text: "dummy text",
            textId: 1,
            sequenceNo: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

let me assume your filterObject should be like below(it would b selected or not)

```
var filterObj = {
  country: "germany",
  companyCode: null,
  companyHiringType: null,
  processName: "process1"
};
```

where you are selecting or not selecting radio buttons (if not selected than the value of that property would be null)

and here is the logic for filter data

```
var f = data.filter(a => {
  return (filterObj.country == null || filterObj.country == a.country)
    && (filterObj.companyCode == null || filterObj.companyCode == a.companyCode)
    && (filterObj.companyHiringType == null || filterObj.companyHiringType == a.companyHiringType)
    && (filterObj.processName == null || filterObj.processName == a.processName);
});
```

Here is your result

```
console.log(f);
```

hope this will help you.

let me know if you need anything more or not clear about this or something wrong.

Note : I have given only that code which will filter data based on 4 parameters (if paramter/property have value or not)

thanks

Comment: the "data" here, Is it an array that I will have to define somewhere or is it something else

Comment: ohh soryy, i forgot to declare data var, in your case it will came from server but stll i have edit answer look into and let me know if need anything more

Comment: hi kushal, i have updated the code. Would you please help me with [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379976/angular-show-data-on-the-user-screen-based-on-the-values-from-the-form) Will we be able to use your filtering method in this condition?

Comment: hi Menime please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379976/angular-show-data-on-the-user-screen-based-on-the-values-from-the-form/59396548#59396548 and try using that solution, let me know after using it. thanks